# Sed doesn't process all script lines

Tags: sed

I have problem with my [sed script](http://pastebin.com/2Hik91KG). I process [this](http://pastebin.com/2WqbA8WU) data using the above script.

The problem is that, the lines from script:

```
/^$/d
s/ $/ajes/g
```

doesn't work. Of course it will work if I process data again.

This doesn't work:

```
sed -f script.sed -i data.file
```

but this will work (double procesing):

```
sed -f script.sed -i data.file
sed -f script.sed -i data.file
```

Why is that? Where is problem? Why I can't process it once with all results?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow (SO). Please do a minimum formatting to your questions, so that is is easily readable. This would help you get answers quicker and accurate. Check formatting [tips](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Harken to the collective wisdom of Stack Overflow: Don't try to process HTML or XML with regular expressions, they aren't the right tool. It is much better to use a programming language (any programming language) with an XML/HTML parser and generate your desired output from the parse tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is that you have just one line. And `sed` reads it once and tries execute each command one by one, while the whole line is in the patterns space. When you substitute something to `\n` it is still just one string and it is in the pattern space. It wasn't divided in multiple strings and reread one by one.

Obviously `/^$/` doesn't match to your `\n\n` and `s/ $/ajes/g` doesn't match to your any space before `\n`. That's the reason why that doesn't work the way you expect.

You can solve the problem with modifying "non working" commands to

```
s/\n\+/\n/g # equals to /^$/d
s/ \n/ajes\n/g # equals to s/ $/ajes/g
```

Comment: GNU sed has a multi-line flag `m` in the substitution command which allows `^` and `$` to match start and end of a line, so `s/ $/ajes/mg` would work. However it does not apply to an address so `/^$/m` is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You have many substitutions there. Let's say you have substitutions

- Rule A
- Rule B
- Rule C.

So, the problem here is if *Rule A* initially does not match and then Rule B or C matches resulting in a pattern that would match again with A after replacement, then Rule A would not come into effect for that line. So, you need to analyze the order in which the substitutions would be processed and hopefully you'll find the mistake.

Hope this helps you in the proper direction.

Comment: This rules was builded one at a time (from top to bottom). If you check only first 5 'rules' (last will be /^$/d) then you will see that it still doesnt work, but it should.